# How to provide permissions to file while creating it using single line UNIX command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm currently working on below Unix command which generates a text file with 644 permissions but i have to create with 777 permission. How can we fit in the permission part in the below command?

`find /home/temp/{a_File_Data.csv,b_File_Data.csv,c_File_Data.csv,d_File_Data.csv} |xargs -n 1 basename > /home/temp/File_Data.txt`

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 644`) and if you have had world writable executable files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, an output redirect will never add the `x` executable permission, that is for your safety.
But you can get the `666` permissions by setting your umask before your command:

```
$ umask 000
```

And you can restore later to the previous value, that seems to be:

```
$ umask 022
```